# In static method bindings that exist inside DataTemplates, is it possible to pass in the instance of the entity?

Tags: xaml, uwp

Example:

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="FooEntity">
    <Grid Background="{x:Bind MyClass.MyStaticBindingMethod(???)}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

It’s easy enough to pass in properties of the entity, but I can’t see a way to pass in the instance itself. Is this feature not supported? I could store a reference to `this` in `FooEntity` with a property called `Instance` (for example), and then go `MyClass.MyStaticBindingMethod(Instance)`, but just want to make sure there isn't a cleaner way.

Relevant docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass the instance itself onto a `DataTemplate`. 
The `DataTemplate` is only responsible for describing the visual structure of a data object and therefore its not part of its job to hold a explicit reference to any CLR object.

`DataTemplate` is defined to extend the visual structure of data objects, such as `GridView`/`ListView`, and those already handle the possibility of referencing to Collections, by setting the `ItemsSource` dependency property. Taking advantage of this, the `DataTemplate` simply exposes the customization of your visual structure. However this visual structure should be followed with the necessary bindings, to achieve your desired custom behavior.

If you are dealing with `x:Bind`, you will have to set the `x:DataType`, to the type of the Collection which you are setting as the Control ItemsSource, because the compiler needs that information at compile-time. 
That is not a problem for `Binding` because those are evaluated at runtime, with the help of reflection.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand correctly, but to bind `this`, meaning the entity directly, you can just use empty binding:

```
Background="{x:Bind}"
```

or

```
Background="{Binding}"
```

This however means that `FooEntity` should derive from `Brush` so that it is compatible with `Background` type.

Comment: I think the question was regarding if it was possible or not to directly pass the instance of a data object onto the DataTemplate. Not the definition of a custom type, but rather a specific instance of that type.
But that is not the job of the DataTemplate, but rather the job of the dependency objects defined within it.

Comment: Nevertheless, would your code work without an higher level dependency property actually binding to an instance of FooEntity? x:DataType only tells the type, the type for which is intented the DataTemplate to be exposed, and you certainly bind it like you did, but you would still need to provide an instance in any other place ...

Comment: I am more so asking what I would replace the three question marks "???" with to pass the data object into the static "MyStaticBindingMethod()" method. Currently, it seems only possible to pass in the values of _properties_ of the data object.